# Duplicated node when getting mysql hierarchy into JSON object using Java

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am using Spring to return a JSON object as a response from a hierarchy represented in two Mysql tables.

```
------------    -----------------     
| Concepts |    | Relationships |
|----------|    |---------------|
| id       |    | relation_id   |
| title    |    | concept_id_1  |
------------    | concept_id_2  |
                -----------------
```

In order to do this I have the method `getChildren` that returns all children of a `concept`.

I am using these methods as follows to get a hierarchical structure from mysql.

---

```
public String getPath(Concept concept, Set<Concept> children){
    if (children.size() > 0){

        Set<Concept> newNodes = new HashSet<>();
        ArrayList<String> returnedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        String currentString = getChildrenString(concept, children);
        return currentString;
    }
    return getMainString(concept, "");
}
```

---

```
public String getChildrenString(Concept concept, Set<Concept> children){
    ArrayList<String> returnedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Concept node : children){
        String currentString = "{'id':" + concept.getId() + ","
                                + "'title':'" + concept.getDescription() + "',"
                                + "'nodes':[" + getPath(node, getChildrens(node)) + "]}";
        returnedStrings.add(currentString);
    }
    StringBuilder fullList = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s: returnedStrings){
        fullList.append(s+"");
    }
    return fullList.toString();
}
```

---

```
public String getEmptyString(Concept concept){

    return "{'id':"+ concept.getId() + ","
            + "'title':'" + concept.getDescription() + "',"
            + "'nodes': []}";
}
```

---

It all starts from here from a known concept.

```
String test = getPath(concept, children);
```

The CORRECT response I am expecting for certain concept is like this:

```
{
    'id': 160000,
    'title': 'root',
    'nodes': [{
        'id': 160039,
        'title': 'Therapeutic Uses',
        'nodes': [{
            'id': 160001,
            'title': 'Anti-Allergic Agents',
            'nodes': []
        }, {
            'id': 160002,
            'title': 'Anti-Infective Agents',
            'nodes': [{
                'id': 160004,
                'title': 'Anti-Infective Agents, Local',
                'nodes': [{
                    'id': 160015,
                    'title': 'Hands Sanitizers',
                    'nodes': []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

However, this code is returning the following string where the nodes are being duplicated, and I can't understand why this is happening or which part of the recursivity is causing this problem.

You can see the concept **160039** is repeating in the answer returned by this code.

```
{
    'id': 160000,
    'title': 'root',
    'nodes': [{
        'id': 160039,
        'title': 'Therapeutic Uses',
        'nodes': [{
            'id': 160001,
            'title': 'Anti-Allergic Agents',
            'nodes': []
        }]
    }, {
        'id': 160039,
        'title': 'Therapeutic Uses',
        'nodes': [{
            'id': 160002,
            'title': 'Anti-Infective Agents',
            'nodes': [{
                'id': 160004,
                'title': 'Anti-Infective Agents, Local',
                'nodes': [{
                    'id': 160015,
                    'title': 'Hands Sanitizers',
                    'nodes': []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

What could be the cause of this in my code, how can I get the correct response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writting this question I noticed I was returning the full string for each **father** node, that's why they were repeating.

Changing this method to return the string after it gets all the other children strings for a node, gives me the correct answer.

```
public String getChildrenString(Concept concept, Set<Concept> children ){
    ArrayList<String> returnedStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Concept node : children){
        String nodeString = getPath(node, hierarchy.getChildrens(node), entity, hierarchy);
        returnedStrings.add(nodeString);
    }


    StringBuilder fullList = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s: returnedStrings){
        fullList.append(s+"");
    }
    return "{'id':" + concept.getId() + ","
            + "'title':'" + concept.getDescription() + "'," +
            "'nodes':[" + fullList.toString() + "]}";
}
```